# what are these numbers in my mode line?

Tags: text-editing

I'm in text-mode.   Just upgraded to GNU EMACS 29.2.   I'm getting two rows of 12 hex numbers in my mode line.   They are static and unchanging during editing.   What does the EMACS community refer to these as?   What use are they to me?    How do I get rid of them?   (Sorry if EMACS is not my life calling. And I did try to RTFM, but if I don't know what they're called I'm SOL.)
[image]

Comment: Show the lines you're talking about. Paste their text here. (Only if you can't do that for some reason, paste a screenshot.)

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Here is a screenshot:

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, but can you clarify what OS you are on, and whether you are using the Emacs GUI or running inside a terminal emulator? A screenshot of just the window, without any background, would also clarify things.

Answer (score 3):

Two rows? My psychic debugger says that these are replacement glyphs for characters that you don’t have a font for. Some font renderers use a �, others make a box with the hexadecimal character number in it.

Edit:

The screenshot that you added shows that I am correct. You can see that each group of four hex digits has a box around it, although the boxes do blend in with the modeline border a bit.

Weirdly though, the characters that it couldn’t render are all in ASCII! Usually every font has glyphs for those, and even if this one didn’t you would expect it to fall back to some other font that does.

FWIW, it says “Xfer.txt    ” which I assume is just the filename, since that’s usually what goes in that spot on the modeline.

Comment: Is your psychic debugger open-source? I'd like a copy please :-)

Comment: @NickD: The standard GNU psychic copier should work, for that.

Comment: @NickD  I added a snip to my post.   (For some reason there was no option to add a snip to a subsequent comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, missing fonts.   My .emacs sets a particular font (Luncinda Console) that perhaps the Gods don't favor anymore.  That bottom line of codes read out in hex  ASCII equal to "Xfer.txt" which is the name of the file I'm visiting. (Perhaps it's UniCode notation?) Thanks all.